# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, proxy, nuget-package

Please note we have corporate proxy configured, this link(https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json) i can able to open in chrome browser but getting issue in VS 2019 nuget console
OS : windows servere 2012 R2

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Aws.png)

Comment: What is the actual question here? What have you tried/looked for and didnt work?

Comment: @Croolman Im trying to restore nuget package but server is not allowing to load the nuget